# Selenium explicit wait upper limit

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium to do some automated testing in a C# app.  I have a component that's not disappearing after the 90 seconds explicit wait.  Is there an upper limit to the timeout:

```
Driver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("section > h1 > img")), 90);
```

I haven't found anything indicating there's an upper limit.

Comment: Is it always the case that the element always disappears after 90 seconds or more? Or does it disappears in less time as well (sometime)? What is the minimum & maximum time limit you observed for the element to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say about explicit wait upper limit, but if you want to make it more you can put the wait in loop. So the loop will make it 90*number of loops.

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverWait` constructor is `WebDriverWait(IWebDriver, TimeSpan)` [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) has several properties, one of them is `Days`, witch receives `double` as parameter. So theoretically you can do

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromDays(double.MaxValue));
```

And see what happens first, your explicit wait ends or [the sun goes supernova](http://chandra.harvard.edu/resources/faq/sources/snr/snr-31.html) :)

(The script will probably crash much sooner).